# error JAVA_HOME para React Native, pero ya tengo instalado JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

al darle un `npm run android` me arroja el siguiente error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\jdk-20.0.2\bin Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
```

Pero yo ya tengo instalado java, de echo si hago un `java -version` en la terminal me arroja lo siguiente:

```
openjdk version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Nose si estoy declarando mal las variable de entorno o necesito instalar algo mas aparte de java. Pero dejo una imagen de como tengo declarada la variable de entorno:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Variables de entorno
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien reinicie mi PC y todavia sigue apareciendo el problema. Si alguien me podria decir una solucion se lo agradeceria.

Dejo la foto del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Ivan, podrías mostrarnos como instalaste JAVA?. puedes ver [aquí](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/attachments/article/389/CU00610B%20configurar%20java%20en%20windows%20variables%20entorno%20java_home%20y%20path.pdf) para ver como configurar después de la instalación.

Comment: Hola marco, lo instale a traves de la paguina oficial de oracle https://www.oracle.com/ar/java/technologies/downloads/, gracias por pasarme ese pdf

Comment: Podrías probar descargar una versión mas baja del jdk, @Cortinico recomienda la versión 17 podría ser que aun no es compatible el jdk 20 referencia:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34103

Comment: Hola @LucasGinard  instale pero me sigue apareciendo el error, ya nose que sera el problema. Por que si pongo la version de java que tengo me aparece

Comment: Yya lo pude resolver, dejo la solucion aqui por la dudas, Me falta agregar dentro de Path en la seccion de "Variables de usuario para ..." la ruta donde tengo instalado JAVA que es -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17